# How to convert a float numpy.ndarray to list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

here is my code

```
import numpy
a = numpy.arange(0.5, 1.5, 0.1, dtype=numpy.float64)
print(a)
print(a.tolist())

>>>[0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4]
>>>[0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7999999999999999, 0.8999999999999999, 0.9999999999999999, 1.0999999999999999, 1.1999999999999997, 1.2999999999999998, 1.4]
```

When trying to convert **numpy array** to **list** getting this problem with value like ***0.7999999999999999*** in place of ***0.8***

please help me to convert **numpy array** to normal python **list** without losing the **decimal value.**

Comment: Numpy arrays have a "pretty" representation which hides some of the digits. This can be controlled via [`numpy.set_printoptions`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html)

Comment: the suggestion is not working because when im printing variable "a" im getting te value without losing decimal but when im converting variable "a" to a list then im losing the decimal values

Comment: You're not gaining or losing any precision in the conversion. This is purely a difference in display handling.

Comment: if i use numpy.set_printoptions maybe im going to get 0.7 instead of 0.8

Comment: "if i use numpy.set_printoptions maybe im going to get 0.7 instead of 0.8" - no you're not. That's an unfounded fear.

Comment: can you please give me example how to use it when im converting an array i can do that for a single value but how can i do that to a array?

Comment: use np.round to set the level of precision on the array data

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy

a = numpy.arange(0.5, 1.5, 0.1, dtype=numpy.float64)

print(a)

a = numpy.round(a.astype(numpy.float64), 1)

print (a)

print (a.tolist())
```

Output:

```
[0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4]
[0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.  1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4]
[0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4]
```

You can use `numpy.round()` with `astype()` method to round your float, getting something consistant upon `tolist()` conversion.

Comment: If that is usefull, think about accepting the answer ;) (click gray tick top left of my answer!)

Answer (score 1):

By the conversion via `.tolist()` you're not gaining or loosing any precision. You're just converting to another data type which chooses to represent itself differently. You seem to be thinking that by the conversion it turns the `0.8` into `0.7999999999999999`, but the situation is, it has never been `0.8`. This is due to [limited floating point precision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/3767239). You can verify yourself:

```py
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.arange(0.5, 1.5, 0.1, dtype=numpy.float64)
>>> a
array([0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1. , 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4])
>>> a[3]
0.7999999999999999
```

The situation is that that every type can decide how its instances are represented via [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) or [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__). In this specific case `np.ndarray` decides to show a rounded version of its elements for more clarity. This can be controlled via [`numpy.set_printoptions`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html). This function only affects how arrays are displayed:

```py
>>> numpy.set_printoptions(floatmode='unique')
>>> a
array([0.5               , 0.6               , 0.7               ,
       0.7999999999999999, 0.8999999999999999, 0.9999999999999999,
       1.0999999999999999, 1.1999999999999997, 1.2999999999999998,
       1.4               ])
```

A note on [`np.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) from the docs:

> When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent. It is better to use [`numpy.linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace) for these cases.

Here are the results for `linspace`:

```py
>>> np.linspace(0.5, 1.5, 11)
array([0.5               , 0.6               , 0.7               ,
       0.8               , 0.9               , 1.                ,
       1.1               , 1.2000000000000002, 1.3               ,
       1.4               , 1.5               ])
```